Save tcolorbox text height and reuse in another one
Here is a small example of a situation.
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newlength{\mylength}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[text height=50pt]
\tcbtextheight
\global\mylength\tcbtextheight
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[text height=\mylength]
\tcbtextheight
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[text height=50pt,title={Title}]
\tcbtextheight
\global\mylength\tcbtextheight
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[text height=\mylength,title={Title}]
\tcbtextheight
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}

Here is the result.

The expected result would be to only have every tcolorbox of text height 5ex, but that is clearly not the case. I don't really understand why \tcbtextheight is not equal to the value of the text height key.

"For boxes with a fixed /tcb/height→ P. 59, this property can be used inside the box content text.", but your boxes don't use a fixed height, they use a fixed text height.

The text height=50pt key doesn't fix the box height ? Looking at the source code, I think so since I see a \tcb@fixedheighttrue on line 409 of the tcolorbox.sty file.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Your last example actually shows that you were right.

When /tcb/geometry node is set true (usually indirectly set by skin options), five TikZ nodes are created for each tcolorbox. Among them the frame node has the same size of the current tcolorbox without box shadow.
The remaining work is to store the height of a tikz node globally in a dimension and find a moment to execute such assignment.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newlength{\mylength}     % always set globally
\newlength{\mylengthtemp} % always set locally

\tcbset{
  save height in/.style={
    overlay={%
      \tcbsettoheightofnode{\mylengthtemp}{frame}%
      \global#1\mylengthtemp
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, text height=50pt, save height in=\mylength]
  content
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[height=\mylength]
  content \the\mylength
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, text height=50pt, save height in=\mylength,
    title={Title}]
  content
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[height=\mylength, title={Title}]
  content \the\mylength
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}



If you want to use \tcbtextheight in the body of the box, it will only work for boxes which have a fixed height. See this quick example:
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newlength{\mylength}

\tcbset{enhanced}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[height=50pt]
\tcbtextheight
\global\mylength\tcbtextheight
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[text height=\mylength]

\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[height=50pt,title={Title}]
\tcbtextheight
\global\mylength\tcbtextheight
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[text height=\mylength,title={Title}]

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}


Instead you could use an equal height group to produce boxes of the same height and set the height via minimum for equal height group=diabox:50pt. To make sure that the title does not influence the height of the box, you could detach it:
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newlength{\mylength}

\newtcolorbox{quack}[2][]{
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left,
    boxed title style={sharp corners=south},
    boxed title size=copy,
    minipage boxed title,
    #1,
    IfEmptyF={#2}{sharp corners=north},
    title=#2  
}

\begin{document}

\begin{quack}[equal height group=diabox, minimum for equal height group=diabox:50pt]{}

\end{quack}

\begin{quack}[equal height group=diabox]{}

\end{quack}

\begin{quack}[equal height group=diabox]{Title}

\end{quack}

\begin{quack}[equal height group=diabox]{Title}

\end{quack}

\end{document}



With your answer I learned new features. It seems to me that we obtain the same result without a minipage boxed title .

@pascal974 The minipage boxed title ensures that the title will span the whole width of the box.

The problem for me is that it doesn't seem possible to fix the first tcolorbox text height.

@MB4E You can set minimum for equal height group=diabox:50pt to whatever value you want

The problem is that I gave a simplified version of my situation, in which the height of the first box is calculated automatically by a space to=\myspace process and I therefore do not know this value.

@MB4E So why can't you let the equal height group determine the height? If one of the other boxes is taller you could hide its heigh and get the height of the first one for the equal height group.

Difficult to explain without asking a new question with a complete code example, but I would already like to better understand how \tcbtextheight works, because I don't understand why height=50pt and text height=50pt give the same value.
